# Have Multiple Click-to-Open Dropdown Menus Only Want One Open at a Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

First of all, I am new with javascript, html, and CSS so bear with me. I have looked everywhere for the answer to my question but I can't find anything that works for my specific code.

I am trying to create a webpage that has multiple dropdown menus and that each one opens when the user clicks on it. I am able to do this but an issue occurs. If I open a dropdown menu and then click on another dropdown menu, the first menu remains open. I want the first menu to close when I open a new one.

Here is a section of my html code with 2 of the dropdown menus:

```
<table class="prodMenu">
<tr><td>
<div class="dropdown2">
<button onclick="myFunction('m1')" class="dropbtn2">SPCGuidance</button>
    <div id="m1" class="dropdown2-content">
        <a href="sseonew12.php?run=<?php print $inrun ?>&cycle=<?php print $incyc ?>&sector=<?php print $insect ?>&id=4PR-TORN">[PR]:4-hr Calibrated Tornado Probability</a>
        <a href="sseonew12.php?run=<?php print $inrun ?>&cycle=<?php print $incyc ?>&sector=<?php print $insect ?>&id=4PR-HAIL">[PR]:4-hr Calibrated Hail Probability</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown2">
<button onclick="myFunction('m2')" class="dropbtn2">Reflectivity</button>
    <div id="m2" class="dropdown2-content">
        <a href="sseonew12.php?run=<?php print $inrun ?>&cycle=<?php print $incyc ?>&sector=<?php print $insect ?>&id=3SP-1KM-REFL40">[SP]:3-hr 1-km Reflectivity >=40 dBZ</a>
        <a href="sseonew12.php?run=<?php print $inrun ?>&cycle=<?php print $incyc ?>&sector=<?php print $insect ?>&id=3NPR-1KM-REFL40">[NPRS]:3-hr 1-km Reflectivity >=40 dBZ</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Next is the part of the .js script that interacts with these dropdown menus. I do have a function that closes the open menus if you click somewhere in the window. However, I'm not sure how to make a function that closes the first dropdown menu when another dropdown menu is opened.

```
// When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content.
function myFunction(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks in window.
window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown2-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

And finally here is the part of the CSS script that controls the dropdown menus:

```
/* dropdown2 is for the rest of the dropdown menus. */
.dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #444444;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    width: auto;
    font: bold 10px arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
    background-color: #000066;
    border: none;
}
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 30;
.dropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 160px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
.dropdown2-content a {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    font: 10px arial;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown2 a:hover {
    background: #000066;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

I got it.

For the Javascript part, this successfully closes the current dropdown menu when you click on another, click outside in the window, or click again on the same menu's header.

```
function myFunction(id) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByCLassName("dropdown2-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if ( dropdowns[i] != document.getElementById(id) ) {
                                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                }
          document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks in window.
window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {
                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown2-  content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `jQuery` ?

Comment: I have never used jQuery before but have seen snippets of the code. It's likely possible but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just close all dropdowns before opening the one that was clicked

```
function myFunction(id) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown2-content");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for closing the previous menu when opening another one. However, now if I have a menu open and want to close it clicking on its header no longer works. I have to either click on a different menu or somewhere in the window to close it. Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can include `jQuery` and use it, this will work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.dropbtn2',function(){
        $('.dropbtn2').not(this).next().removeClass('show');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('show');
    });
    $(document).on('click',function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).closest('.dropbtn2').length)
            $('.dropbtn2').next().removeClass('show');
    });    
});
```

```css
/* dropdown2 is for the rest of the dropdown menus. */
.dropbtn2 {
    background-color: #444444;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    width: auto;
    font: bold 10px arial;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
    background-color: #000066;
    border: none;
}
.dropdown2 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 30;
}
.dropdown2-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 160px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #DDDDDD;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
.dropdown2-content a {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    font: 10px arial;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown2 a:hover {
    background: #000066;
    color: #FFF;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="prodMenu">
<tr><td>
<div class="dropdown2">
<button class="dropbtn2">SPCGuidance</button>
    <div id="m1" class="dropdown2-content">
        <a href="#">[PR]:4-hr Calibrated Tornado Probability</a>
        <a href="#">[PR]:4-hr Calibrated Hail Probability</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="dropdown2">
<button class="dropbtn2">Reflectivity</button>
    <div id="m2" class="dropdown2-content">
        <a href="#">[SP]:3-hr 1-km Reflectivity >=40 dBZ</a>
        <a href="#">[NPRS]:3-hr 1-km Reflectivity >=40 dBZ</a>
    </div>
</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the best solution is to use Bootstrap, which can handle these situations right out of the box: see how it works http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

If you for some reason cannot use Bootstrap and can use jQuery, that would be quite easy too. When clicking the button, you would hide all the dropdowns and then show just the adjacent one. It would go something like this:

```
$('.dropbtn2').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown2-content).hide();  // hide all the dropdowns
  $(this).next().show();          // show the next sibling
});
```

If you can use neither Bootstrap nor jQuery, just copy the code you have in the `windows.onclick` part before showing the element in `myFunction`, as Funk Doc said.